# Number of permutations in $S_{a+b}$ with $\operatorname{maj}(\pi)=a$ and $\operatorname{maj}(\pi^{-1})=b$

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

$\DeclareMathOperator\maj{maj}\DeclareMathOperator\inv{inv}$Major index, $\maj$, of a permutation on $1,2,\dotsc,n$ is defined as
$$
\maj(\pi) \mathrel{:=} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i \cdot \chi(\pi(i)\gt \pi(i+1))
$$
where $\chi$ is 1 if the statement inside is true, 0 otherwise.

Let $t_{a,b}$ be the numbers
$$
 t_{a,b} \mathrel{:=} \lvert\{ \pi \in S_{a+b} : \maj(\pi)=a \text{ and }  \maj(\pi^{-1})=b \}\rvert.
$$
Here, $S_{a+b}$ denotes the set of permutations of $1,2,\dotsc,a+b$.
By a result of Foata, one can also look at the pair of statistics $(\maj, \inv)$, and a few other combinations — these pairs of statistics will produce the same numbers.

Now, according to the OEIS entry [A090806](https://oeis.org/A090806), it is proved by Garsia–Gessel that
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{a,b} t_{a,b} q^a t^b = \prod_{i,j \geq 1} \frac{1}{1-q^i t^j}
\qquad (\ast)
\end{equation}
I cannot see exactly where in their paper one can deduce this.

I have tried to prove this myself (mainly by resorting to RSK, the Cauchy identity, and some symmetric function identities).
This leads to the following (which appears in Stanley's EC2):
$$
 \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{z^n}{(1-q)^n[n]_q!(1-t)^n [n]_t!} \sum_{\pi \in S_n} t^{\maj(\pi)} q^{\maj(\pi^{-1})} 
 =
 \prod_{i,j \geq 0} \frac{1}{1-z q^i t^j},
$$
where $[n]_q! \mathrel{:=} [1]_q [2]_q \dotsm [n]_q$, and $[n]_q = 1+q+q^2+\dotsb + q^{n-1}$.
However, I do not see some short way to deduce the above generating function from this.

**Question:** Is there some alternative (more recent?) reference where $(\ast)$ is
stated and easily referenced? Alternatively, someone who can see exactly where in the paper $(\ast)$ is proven?

*Garsia, A. M.; Gessel, I.*, [**Permutation statistics and partitions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(79)90046-X), Adv. Math. 31, 288-305 (1979). [ZBL0431.05007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0431.05007).

Comment: $maj(\pi)$ is $\mbox{definition}$?

Comment: What is $\mathrm{maj}$?

Comment: [Major index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_index).

Comment: @PerAlexandersson, I see you prefer not to use `\label` and `\eqref`.  I apologise for editing in something you didn't want.  The main advantage is that it makes the references clickable links to the equations.  Obviously in a short post rather than a paper it's not a big deal, but it's a nice affordance!  (Or maybe you saw [revision 2](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/384561/2), where the ugly rendered result didn't match the preview.  I fixed that in [revision 3](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/384561/3), and filed a [bug report](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4884).)

Comment: @PerAlexandersson, certainly you are right, and I apologise for my error.  I think I was applying the fix as you were converting it back to the static form.  Anyway I try to edit with a light touch, and the preview seemed to confirm that everything was working, so I apologise that in the end it wound up being ugly.

Comment: @LSpice I appreciate the effort - our edits simply collided as I was adding the definition of major index.

Comment: P.S.  I should say I like your TeX.  I think not enough people make use of the semantic `\dots.` commands.

Comment: Have you tried this? M. S. Cheema and T. S. Motzkin, "Multipartitions and multipermutations," Proc. Symp. Pure Math. 19 (1971), 39-70, eq. (3.1.3).I don't have access here.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan I also tried to find that reference, but it seems hard to access it.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan Ah, yes, I could find it after some work - in remark 6.2, it is mentioned that the number of permutations in S_{r} with maj=a, imaj=b, with a,b<M, and r>2M, is independent of $r$. This is what's mentioned in the OEIS entry, that it stabilizes...

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: You might also like to look into this paper: Don RAWLINGS,  Generalized  Worpitzky  Identifies  with  Applications  to Permutation  Enumeration,  Europ.  J.  Comb., Vol.  2,  1981,  p.  67-78. (This is freely available online.)

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: You're probably aware that the RHS of the above formula for $S_{a+b}$ begins with $i,j=1$ while the latter formula begins with $i,j=0$. That said, the latter formula has extra product in the form $\prod\frac1{1-w^i}$ appearing twice which injects the generating function for integer partitions. Moreover, you know that the latter formula is a Cauchy product for Schur functions.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan Right, that's correct. I was hoping that there's an easy argument to just compare coefficients, if one assumes $n$ is larger than or equal to $a+b$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a derivation of $(\ast)$ from the displayed equation
$$\sum \frac{z^n}{(1-q)^n [n]_q! (1-t)^n [n]_t!} \sum_{\pi \in S_n} q^{\mathrm{maj}(\pi)} t^{\mathrm{maj}(\pi^{-1})} = \prod_{i,j \geq 0} \frac{1}{1-zt^i q^j}.$$

Taking the coefficient of $z^n$ on both sides, we have
$$\frac{\sum_{\pi \in S_n} q^{\mathrm{maj}(\pi)} t^{\mathrm{maj}(\pi^{-1})}}{\prod_{i=1}^n (1-q^i) \prod_{j=1}^n (1-t^j)} = h_n(\{t^i q^j : i,j \geq 0\}).$$
Here the RHS is the complete homogenous symmetric function evaluated on the set of monomials $\{t^i q^j : i,j \geq 0\}$.

Now, $h_n(1, u_1, u_2, u_3, \ldots) = \sum_{k=0}^n h_k(u_1, u_2,\ldots).$ So we can rewrite this RHS to get
$$\frac{\sum_{\pi \in S_n} q^{\mathrm{maj}(\pi)} t^{\mathrm{maj}(\pi^{-1})}}{\prod_{i=1}^n (1-q^i) \prod_{j=1}^n (1-t^j)} = \sum_{k=0}^n h_k(\{ q^i t^j : i,j \geq 0,\ (i,j) \neq (0,0) \}). \qquad (\clubsuit)$$

[According to the OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A090806), the quantity $\# \{ \pi \in S_n : \mathrm{maj}(\pi) = a,\ \mathrm{maj}(\pi^{-1}) = b \}$ stabilizes at $t_{ab}$ as $n \to \infty$; the OP's mention of $n=a+b$ is just a particular value in the stable range. So we can take the limit of both sides of $(\clubsuit)$ as $n \to \infty$ to get
$$\frac{\sum_{a,b \geq 0} t_{ab} q^a t^b}{\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-q^i) \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} (1-t^j)} = 
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} h_k(\{ q^i t^j : i,j \geq 0,\ (i,j) \neq (0,0) \}) = \prod_{\substack{i,j \geq 0 \\ (i,j) \neq (0,0)}} \frac{1}{1-q^i t^j} . \qquad (\diamondsuit)$$

Now cancel common factors from both sides of $(\diamondsuit)$ to get the claim.

---

Here is another approach, which suggests that something more interesting may be going on. Recall that the RS correspondence is a bijection between the symmetric group $S_n$ and pairs of SYT $(T,U)$ of the same shape $\lambda$, where $|\lambda| = n$. We define $\mathrm{maj}(T)$ for an SYT $T$ to be the sum of those $i$ such that $i$ occurs in a strictly higher row of $T$ than $i+1$ does. Then, if RS maps $\pi$ to $(T,U)$, we have
$\mathrm{maj}(\pi)= \mathrm{maj}(T)$ and $\mathrm{maj}(\pi^{-1})= \mathrm{maj}(U)$.

Define $f^{\lambda}(q)$ to be the sum, over $SYT$ of shape $\lambda$, of $q^{\mathrm{maj}(T)}$. So
$$\sum_{\pi \in S_n} q^{\mathrm{maj}(\pi)} t^{\mathrm{maj}(\pi^{-1})} = \sum_{|\lambda| = n} f^{\lambda}(q) f^{\lambda}(t).$$

Given a permutation $\mu$, and $n > |\mu| + \mu_1$, let $\mu[n]$ be the partition $(n-|\mu|, \mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_k)$. So every partition of $n$ is of the form $\mu[n]$ for a unique $\mu$ and that, for any $\mu$, the partition $\mu[n]$ is well defined for $n$ large enough.

It is easy to see that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f^{\mu[n]}(q)$ exists. Set $f^{\mu[\infty]}(q)$ to be $\lim_{n \to \infty} f^{\mu[n]}(q)$.
So we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{\pi \in S_n} q^{\mathrm{maj}(\pi)} t^{\mathrm{maj}(\pi^{-1})} = \sum_{\mu} f^{\mu[\infty]}(q) f^{\mu[\infty]}(t).$$

On the other hand, the Cauchy identity gives
$$\prod_{i,j \geq 1} \frac{1}{1-q^i t^j} = \sum_{\mu} s_{\mu}(q,q^2, \cdots) s_{\mu}(t,t^2, \cdots).$$

So here is the weird thing: It turns out that $f^{\mu[\infty]}(q)$ and $s_{\mu}(q)$ are the same thing! This seems like it should have a combinatorial proof. We can clearly think of $f^{\mu[\infty]}(q)$ as a generating function for tableau of shape $\mu$ with distinct entries, counted by a variant of major index. And $s_{\mu}(q)$ is the generating function for semistandard tableau of shape $\mu$, counted by weight. It feels like there should be an easy bijection here.

Well, I couldn't find one. But it isn't hard to prove the equality using hook length formulas. Let $m = |\mu|$ and let $h_1$, $h_2$, ..., $h_m$
be the hook lengths of $\mu$. Set $M = \sum (i-1) \mu_i$. We have
$$s_{\mu}(q) = \frac{q^M}{\prod_i (1-q^{h_i})} .$$

On the other hand, the hook lengths of $\mu[n]$ are $h_1$, $h_2$, ..., $h_m$ together with an $n-m$ additional hook lengths $S$. The exact set $S$ doesn't matter; what is important is  $\{1,2,\ldots, n-\mu_1-m \} \subseteq S \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots, n \}$. So, by a formula of Stanley (EC2, Cor. 7.21.5), we have
$$f^{\mu[n]}(q) = \frac{q^M (1-q)(1-q^2) \cdots (1-q^N)}{\prod_{s \in S} (1-q^s) \prod_i (1-q^{h_i})}.$$
In the limit as $n \to \infty$, both $(1-q)(1-q^2) \cdots (1-q^N)$ and $\prod_{s \in S} (1-q^s)$ approach $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-q^k)$, so they cancel and we are left with
$$ f^{\mu[\infty]}(q) = \frac{q^M}{\prod_i (1-q^{h_i})} = s_{\mu}(q,q^2, \cdots).$$

Comment: FWIW, I think the stabilization is easy to see if you work with maj and inv instead of maj and imaj. Let $\pi = \pi_1\pi_2\ldots\pi_m \in S_m$ be a permutation, where $m \geq a+b$, and with $\mathrm{maj}(\pi)=a$ and $\mathrm{inv}(\pi)=b$. Since $\mathrm{maj}(\pi)=a$, no descents can occur after the first $a$ positions; since $\mathrm{inv}(\pi)=b$, no letter of $a+b+i$ for $i\geq 1$ can occur in the first $a$ positions. Together these force all $a+b+i$ for $i\geq 1$ to be fixed points. So $\pi$ is really only a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,a+b\}$.

Comment: Should $\neq$ in the second equation be $\geq$?

Comment: Thanks to both of you, you are both right.

Comment: Great answer and comment, SamHopkins and @DavidESpeyer ! This now gives a nice record of this identity! I need this for some background in a paper, so I'll probably include this argument, with proper attributions

Comment: You're welcome. I actually think there is more going on here; see the second proof I added below the horizontal line.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: the $\mu[n]$ construction is very common in representation stability; maybe these computations have some meaning in that context.

Comment: The Cauchy identity can be proved using RSK, and the Garsia-Gessel reference probably does basically the combinatorics you are after.